# Googlemaps.tpk with ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-android

I stored a googlemaps.tpk file in my sdcard. I am trying to run it with ArcGIS but it gives the error file is not a tiled package. My question is that how to run googlemap.tpk file with ArcGIS.

Comment: It needs to go in the ArcGIS_Collector folder http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2014/03/23/using-your-own-basemap-layers-with-collector-for-arcgis/